# Trouble deploying a static Angular / Yeoman project in Travis CI to S3 (Grunt issue)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, travis-ci, yeoman-generator, grunt-usemin

Im trying to deploy a project to S3, but I'm having trouble with the `grunt build` step. Locally on my mac (10.9, node 0.10) the `grunt build` step works perfectly. If I manually deploy to s3 using the command line client everything works.

But when I use Travis, when my scripts get concatenated, it seems to leave out my services and directives. In the Travis log it looks like they should be added though (ex. line 2054).

This is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.10'
before_script:
- gem install compass
- npm install
- npm install bower
- bower install
- npm install grunt-cli
- grunt build
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: AKIAISJMRUQ4YJVE4AYA
  secret_access_key:
    secure:     E1SMwWvV4J2OWS+kQcu/DnCaVR+Jf1wigk+guvlAS9YcqQuaVJNMDiMWJdoHO6tnv3PIY2JtVgxMA4IRpW9F0RDHeJh2k6C5D+szw0x+XRnfbTx57YLw2c1b+IwXKp5Rl7hAzVsvaUZC4NuU6vbwxS+SOKIsICfq6r2VmpS0zoY=
  bucket: lastfm-angular
  on:
    repo: keymholio/lastfm-angular
```

My repo is here: https://github.com/keymholio/lastfm-angular

My travis build is here: https://travis-ci.org/keymholio/lastfm-angular/builds/22743947

Deployed site: http://lastfm-angular.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by commenting out the `concat` step in the `Gruntfile`.

https://github.com/keymholio/lastfm-angular/commit/b4e70a4f2511593c3b1dc62cbd105e182bb7d135

Comment: Since you are deploying the directory created by `grunt build` task, why didn't you include `local-dir: dist` in '.travis.yml' file?  i did that but getting error message like this: `chdir': No such file or directory - dist`